# JS heap size limit

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, discord.js

Sending messages happens every 30 mins by described interval.

```
function startInterval() {
  const interval = 5 * 60 * 1000; // 30 min

  if (intervalId !== undefined) {
    clearInterval(intervalId as number);
  }

  intervalId = setInterval(() => {
    initializeSettingsAndSendMessage();
  }, interval);
}

startInterval();
```

Method `initializeSettingsAndSendMessage()`:

```
for (const setting of settingsList) {
    const discordClient = new DiscordClient(setting);
    const isSuccessStart = await discordClient.start()
    if(!isSuccessStart) {
      continue;
    }
    await discordClient.sendMessagesDependsOnSettingId(discordClient.getSettingId());
}
```

I created separate class DiscordClient, which is used for auth for every bot.

Setting contain *channelId*, *guildId* and *botToken*.

and for every client I am running function `sendMessagesDependsOnSettingId()` , which is used for sending message in channels by *channelId* and *guildId*, something like that:

```
for (const message of messageList) {
    const { content, guildId, channelId, files } = message;
    const guild = this.client.guilds.cache.get(guildId.toString());
    const channel = guild.channels.cache.get(channelId.toString());
    if (!channel) {
      continue;
    }
    if (channel.isText()) {
        await channel.send({
          content: content
        })
    }
}
await this.stop();
```

and in the end I am trying to destory class by `this.stop()` to free memory, but it does not help.

```
public async stop() {
  await this.client.destroy();
}
```

So after running app for a hour, I am getting this message:

[JS heap size error after 1 hour app working](https://i.imgur.com/qDIIOf7.png)

Also debugged snapshots:

[Debug Snapshots, objects allocated between Snapshot 1 and Snapshot 2](https://i.imgur.com/jaGZaKo.png)

[Comparison with 1st snapshot](https://i.imgur.com/8m1YiXW.png)

Snapshot 1 - before initializeSettingsAndSendMessage() started.

Snapshot 2 - after initializeSettingsAndSendMessage() started.

Please advice me steps to reduce RAM using.

I tried to user this.stop() funtion to destroy class, but it does not work.
Also I tried to debug via `--inspect` flag. The results above.

Comment: As a hack you can run this script in a separate process, scheduling it by cron, k8s or w/e system you use. After messages are sent, your script can just exit, and OS will take care of memory usage

Comment: Does your script work if you remove this code? What else you have within your process

Comment: yes, I think it will work, because from the debugged snapshots I see that the large amount of memory goes on discord info, and if I remove it, it will work. 

Else that I have is MessageService/SettingService which is needed to fetch data from sqlite3 database, but I am pretty sure it does not affect RAM too much.

Also I thought that becase I use cache.get() in discord, it caches large amount of info and never cleared. But not sure. 

Still investigating an issue, but thank you for advice with cron/k8s, I will read about this.

Comment: @deathangel908 using cron is not a hack, it's a way more reasonable solution!

Comment: @s1n instead of creating new clients for every run, could you retain the existing clients? On first glance it does seem that the clients arent't properly GC'd.

Comment: I think need to try it. I will test  cron and the retaining the existing clients. thanks.

Comment: But if for example I will have 100 clients in that case, they will be stored in RAM, and it is not a good practice. So cron might be better. I will check it.